# TLS Handshake and rfc3526 MODP Group - 14

Tags: java, ssl, cryptography, diffie-hellman, jsse

I am trying to figure out how can i set the 2048-bit MODP Group-14 on my Netty Based Server TLS setup. Server Impl. using standard Java APIs from JSSE.

[rfc3526 2048-bit MODP Group-14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-3)

Used JDK is 1.8

To set the key size, I have used -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 as specified in [Customizing Size of Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman Keys](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#customizing_dh_keys).

I am not sure it is fullfiling all the requirements of rfc3526 2048-bit MODP Group-14. I dont know how to verify it except key length. Is there any example to set modp while creating sslcontext or sslengine?

Comment: Any idea to fix this???

Comment: Well, yes, now we do: http://serverfault.com/a/798036/143023 You might want to use more (popular) tags, not just [tag:java] and [tag:jsse].